# Having multiple images on one webpage be shareable to facebook

Tags: facebook, joomla, share

So for the webpage I want there to be 5 different images that are shareable to Facebook. I have it all set up with the buttons, but cannot figure out how to make it so that a person can pick which one they share. If I use opengraph then I can only select one image. Is it possible to have multiple images be shareable to facebook from one webpage?

Answer (score 0):

A share on Facebook only allows for one image that will be displayed in the feed etc.. If you want to have multiple images, your only option is to combine the images the user selected into one and provide this in the og:image tag of your URL.

If your only goal is to let the user choose one out of *n* different pictures, simply add multiple og:image tags, this should allow the user to then choose one of them in the Share dialog.